# Unable to add reference

Tags: .net, oracle11g

I am unable to add reference of oracle.dataaccess.dll in visual studio 2003.

i am using oracle 11g and windows 8 (64 bit).

Following error appears: **This is not a valid assembly or COM component. Only assemblies with extension 'dll' and COM components can be referenced.** Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component

Comment: Visual Studio **2003**?? This is ancient. It is very possible that it simply doesn't understand current .NET assemblies.

Comment: Yeah I know but I have a solution developed in VS2003.is there any solution.???

Comment: Interesting that this was asked only 2 days ago. I'm running into the same issue with Oracle 11g on a server that only has Visual Studio 2003 on it.